# Java 8 groupBy and reduce not summing up values in the column

Tags: java-8, grouping, reduce

I am trying to use Java8 groupby and reduce feature to sum elements based on grouping but the code doesnt seem to be working for me.

Here is my data from the Dtolist that I am trying to map and extract in an excel sheet.
[image]

My requirement is that for every DTO object I want this kilometersNumber to be summed up based on groupingBy TruckId. So , the highlighted columns should be having summed up values for same TruckId(******Contract flotte****)

This is my DTO:

'''public class CostsTruckWsDTO implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String truckId;

private LocalDate period;

private Bigdecimal KilometersNumber;

private String periodStartDate;
```

---

Here is the logic::
''costsTruckWsDTO.setGroupBy(TruckId.toUpperCase());

Map<String, List> mapCostsTruck = costsTruck.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getGroupBy().toUpperCase()));
for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry : mapCostsTruck.entrySet()) {

```
        BigDecimal totalKm = entry.getValue().stream().map(x -> x.getKilometersNumber()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                BigDecimal::add);
```

}
}''

But what am getting is value for kilometere is not geeting added as per the screenshot.
Can anybody pls help me what I am missing here!!!
Highly appreciate

Comment: can you please edit your question - there are some formatting issues which makes the reading hard. 
When grouping the different `truckId`s into the map (before summing their distance), do you get the expected result?

Comment: How did you construct `costsTruck`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the operation of grouping together with the operation of summing using two collectors:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> result = trucks.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CostsTruckWsDTO::getTruckId, 
                      Collectors.mapping(CostsTruckWsDTO::getKilometersNumber, Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response. I see that my grouping is in place just its not summing up and setting against the field. Here is the code :

Comment: `Map<String, List<CostsTrucksDTO>> mapCostsTruck = costsTruck.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getGroupBy().toUpperCase()));
//This above map is correct with correct grouping
for (Map.Entry<String, List<CostsTrucksDTO>> entry : mapCostsTruck.entrySet()) {
    BigDecimal totalKm =  BigDecimal.ZERO;
    totalKm = entry.getValue().stream().map(x -> x.getKilometersNumber()).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,
      BigDecimal::add);}`